# How to correctly initialize WebGL on Chrome in headless environment to work with MapBox?

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

UI does not render GL elements causing test to fail with an error: Failed to initialize WebGL.

Tests are being executed via Jenkins on a docker instance (python:3.7-alpine3.9).

In local testing have made attempts to use various webdriver options including --use-gl=osmosa/swiftshader and others. Problem with those is, i don't really get a feedback if particular option was successfully applied.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless") 
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--use-gl=swiftshader")
options.add_argument("--enable-webgl")
options.add_argument("--ignore-gpu-blacklist")
web_driver = WebDriver(executable_path='chromedriver', options=options)
```

Installed those little guys as well.
apk add mesa-osmesa
apk add mesa-gl

None of above lead to a happy ending. 
Visiting webpage https://browserleaks.com/webgl where webgl information is returned in context of used browser returned ambigous information that WebGL being support: False, but supported but disabled.

```
This browser supports WebGL: False (supported, but disabled in browser settings, or blocked by extensions)
This browser supports WebGL 2: False (supported, but disabled in browser settings, or blocked by extensions)
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue will be resolved client side, with change registry key in the below path:

Path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
Name: Disable3DAPIs
Value: 0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).